# Tetris clearing full rows

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I am making a tetris game using haskell and I am having troubles implementing the last feature, clearing the full rows and decrementing every tuple above it.

as the bord I am using a list with [(xcoord , ycoord) ] with only the coordinates that are occupied.

I am thinking about checking if the list has 15 (width of the tetris game ) tuples with the same ycoord and so, if this is the case the row is full and everything above the row is gets their ycoord decremented by 1.

```
removeFullRow :: [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
removeFullRow list = ?
```

What is the best way going about this in haskell ?

Thx for the help

Comment: Are you sure this is the best way to handle this? What about an `[[Int]]`? Then clearing the last row, is just "popping" the head of the list, and appending an empty row at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a fairly complicated thing to handle, given the data structure, `[(Int, Int)]`, used. I'd recommend a more appropriate one.

With that said, there are several stages. Here's one possible way of doing it:

1. Sort the input list by (y, x) values (you can `Data.Tuple.swap` the tuples to convert from (x, y)) so that all the elements on each row are next to each other and so that the lower rows are earlier in the list.
2. Group the input list by y values so that all the rows are in different sublists.
3. Convert the tuples to just x values.
4. Filter out any sublists that have 15 elements.
5. Reconstitute the tuples by adding the index of each sublist as its elements' y values.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method we will use:

1. We fold over the list counting how many items are in each row
2. We if any rows are full
3. we filter out the coördinates of items in full rows

Intro

```
import Data.Map as M
```

Step 1

```
countInRows :: [(Int,Int)] -> M.Map Int Int
countInRows items =
  M.fromListWith (+) [(row,1) | (col,row) <- items]
```

This works by:

1. converting your list elements into things that say “I know about 1 full square in row *n*”
2. Merging them together by adding up the number of full squares for each row,
3. Putting that result into a map associating a row with how full it is

Step 2

```
isFull :: Int -> M.Map Int Int -> Int -> Bool
isFull width counts row =
  M.findWithDefault 0 row counts >= width
```

This will find how full a row is (if it isn’t in the map then it must have 0 full squares). If there are as many full squares as the board is wide then the row must be full.

Step 3 (putting it all together)

```
import Data.Map as M
removeFullRows :: Int -> [(Int,Int)] -> [(Int,Int)]
removeFullRows items =
  filter (not . isFull . row) items where
  counts = M.fromListWith (+) [(row,1) | (col,row) <- items]
  isFull row =
    M.findWithDefault 0 row counts >= width
  row (x,y) = y
```

We filter out the items by getting the row, seeing if it is full, and if not then we keep the item.